# SFTP to retrieve files from Windows server to Linux server using java

Tags: java, windows, linux, sftp, file-transfer

I am working on file download functionality.All my files are in Windows server,is there any Library in java which can be used to do SFTP to transfer files from remote windows server to Linux server where my Java app is running?

Answer (score 0):

use JScape's secure FTP library from [this link](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/74033/Secure-File-Transfer-with-Java-SFTP-Library)

Comment: can I do sftp from windows server to Linux  with this library?

Comment: yes as long as you have sftp enabled to linux I do not see a point why not

Comment: Being very new to SFTP/Secure file transfer I didn't ask question in the right way.Can you see Updated question.

Comment: Can I still use this above library for my requirement or Do I need another one?

Comment: Is this not a Open source Library.I am looking for a Open Source API.

Answer (score 0):

given you have access to both peers, you can use [SSLServerSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html)/[SSLSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) for the connection on both ends.

Edit:

some basic example on how to establish connection and read/write data: http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

wow, hope you are satisfied with our software :)

thank you,

Comment: Yes I do have access to both servers.Can you please give any examples of this? By the we have used tanuki wrapper in my project.That's great.

Comment: Thanks.I will try to implement this in my App.

Comment: @duskwuff the original question was only about transferring a file secure, for which a ssl connection could certainly be used. sftp was added to the question in a later edit...